# removing numbers from a column in python pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I want to remove all numbers within the entries of a certain column in a Python pandas dataframe. Unfortunately, commands like `.join()` and `.find()` are not iterable (when I define a function to iterate on the entries, it gives me a message that floating variables do not have `.find` and `.join` attributes). Are there any commands that take care of this in pandas?

```
def remove(data):

  for i in data if not i.isdigit():
    data=''         
    data=data.join(i)  
    return data

myfile['column_name']=myfile['column_name'].apply(remove())
```

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a before and after DataFrame example so we could determine exactly what you mean and need.

Comment: I should have explained better, what I want to do is to  convert entries like tin1t9in to tintin, meaning to remove digital characters of an entry in a column.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all numbers like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame ( {'x' : ['1','2','C','4']})
df[ df["x"].str.isdigit()  ] = "NaN"
```

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to know for sure without a data sample, but your code implies `data` contains strings since you call `isdigit` on the elements.

Assuming the above, there are many ways to do what you want. One of them is conditional list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.DataFrame({'x':['p','2','3','d','f','0']})
out = [ x if x.isdigit() else '' for x in s['x'] ]
# Output: ['', '2', '3', '', '', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or look at using `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` to cast the column as numeric and eliminate non-numeric values:

Using @Raidex setup:

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'x':['p','2','3','d','f','0']})
pd.to_numeric(s['x'], errors='coerce')
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    0.0
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

EDIT to handle either situation.

```
s['x'].where(~s['x'].str.isdigit())
```

Output:

```
0      p
1    NaN
2    NaN
3      d
4      f
5    NaN
Name: x, dtype: object
```

OR

```
s['x'].where(s['x'].str.isdigit())
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1      2
2      3
3    NaN
4    NaN
5      0
Name: x, dtype: object
```

Comment: but this isnt removing the numbers though?

Comment: @ChristianSloper Nope, you see the output results.

Comment: So you are not answering the question?

Comment: @ChristianSloper Okay. if you say so.  I'll let the OP expand on his request. Thank you for input.

Comment: He says.. how to remove numbers, and you show how to remove non numbers? I dont see how you are answering the question at all, but sure.